# Error when passing a Swift implementation of a Kotlin interface to a Kotlin method

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-native

I'm doing some experimenting with Kotlin Native on iOS, and one thing I wanted to try was having a Swift implementation of a Kotlin-defined interface. However, I end up crashing when I try to pass that Swift object back up to the Kotlin code.

I'm using the kotlin gradle plugin version 1.2.30 and kotlin native version 0.6.1

A minimal example follows. The Kotlin code is being compiled to a framework with the name KotlinCommon, which is then included in the xcode project.

DemoClass.kt

```
class DemoClass {
    fun process(dependency: Dependency) {
        dependency.foo()
    }
}

interface Dependency {
    fun foo()
}
```

SwiftDependency.swift

```
import KotlinCommon

class SwiftDependency : KotlinCommonDependency {
    func foo() {
        NSLog("hello")
    }
}
```

Then, from my iOS UI I try to run

```
let module = KotlinCommonDemoClass()
let dependency = SwiftDependency()
module.process(dependency: dependency)
```

The third line causes a crash with the following error:

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x101858d20 of class 'KotlinNativeDemo.SwiftDependency' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[KotlinNativeDemo.SwiftDependency toKotlin:]
```

Is this use-case not supported by Kotlin Native? Or could there be something I'm configuring wrong?

Comment: Read the error message.. `toKotlin` is a method that is not implemented in `SwiftDependency`..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently `SwiftDependency` is required to subclass `NSObject`:

```
class SwiftDependency : NSObject, KotlinCommonDependency {
    func foo() {
        NSLog("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Just for my own edification, is that requirement documented anywhere?

Comment: Not yet. Currently the best documentation for compilation of Kotlin code to Objective-C framework is [calculator sample](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/calculator).